# Понять конкретную позицию одинаковых элементов в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

У нас есть вот такой вот список, нужно получить позицию каждого элемента в этом списке, к примеру ниже, но дело в том что в нем первые 3 элемента всегда могут быть одинаковые, вопрос как тогда получать индекс каждого этого элемента тк как обычный метод всегда выдает  0 и ссылается на первый элемент.

```
tictactoe_board = [['', '', '', ' 1⃣ '], ['', '', '', ' 2⃣ '], ['', '', '', ' 3⃣ ']]

for i, line in enumerate(tictactoe_board):
  for k in line:
    print(f"listind: {i} itemind: {tictactoe_board[i].index(k)}") #Тут уже выводить позицию элемента аля 0,1 #0 - индекс второго списка, 1, его позиция в этом списке, и так ко всем вложенным там спискам и элементам в них.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это необходимо проделать для каждого элемента, то, возможно, что-нибудь такое подойдёт:

```
for i in range(len(tictactoe_board)):
    for k in range(len(tictactoe_board[i])):
        print("Element " + str(tictactoe_board[i][k]) + " at " + str(i) + " : " + str(k))
```

Например, для `tictactoe_board = [[1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3]]`:

```
Element 1 at 0 : 0                                                                                                                            
Element 2 at 0 : 1                                                                                                                            
Element 2 at 0 : 2                                                                                                                            
Element 3 at 0 : 3                                                                                                                            
Element 1 at 1 : 0                                                                                                                            
Element 2 at 1 : 1                                                                                                                            
Element 2 at 1 : 2                                                                                                                            
Element 3 at 1 : 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял Вашу задумку попробуйте так:

```py
tictactoe_board = [['', '', '', ' 1⃣ '], ['', '', '', ' 2⃣ '], ['', '', '', ' 3⃣ ']]

for i, line in enumerate(tictactoe_board):
    for n, k in enumerate(line):
        print(f"Элемент:{tictactoe_board[i][n]} Индекс: {i} {n}")
```

Собственно i-n получается как раз ваши индексы.